# Chebyshev Inequality and Counting Probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

I am having trouble with this question.

> Using Chebyshev’s inequality for case (a), and by computing the probabilities in cases (b) and (c), find which is the most and which is the least probable of the following three events:
>   (a) A normally distributed random variable X ∼ N(μ,σ2) falls more than 4σ away from the meanμ,i.e. |X−μ|≥4σ;
>   (b) A fair coin (P(H) = P(T)) shows heads on three independent tosses;
>   (c) A fair coin shows tails on two of four independent tosses.

So I know that for part b the probability is 1/8, and for part b the probability is 1/2.

I just don't know about Chebyshev therefore I cannot answer which case would be the most probable and which case the least.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Chebyshev: $P(|X-\mu| > t) \leq \frac{Var[X]}{t^2}$. Can you work from there?

Comment: Yes thank you, then i would get from that 1/16, therefore that is the least probable case and part c with probability 1/2 is the most probable case